# How to program a convoluted Indicator calculations, that requires the previous period value in its calculation?

Tags: math, charts, trading, technical-indicator

If we take the Accumulation/Distribution indicator for example.

Investopedia lists the steps as:

> 1. Money Flow Multiplier = [(close  -  low) - (high - close)] /(high - low)
> 2. Money Flow Volume = Money Flow Multiplier x volume for the period
> 3. Accumulation/Distribution= previous Accumulation/Distribution + current period's Money Flow

The third step is what confuses me, how can I calculate A/D when I don't have the previous A/D, which requires the previous A/D and so on...

There are other indicators that are similar where the indicator requires the indicator itself to be calculated. So how is it done?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [economics.se].

Comment: But I would set the A/D to `0` for periods that you don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a common software approach to this:

Your case has a trivial convolution, with a depth of just 1. There are some deeper convolution indicators, going in this very same principle just a bit deeper.

### Solution:

find a so called "neutral" value, that the calculus is dependent on and inject it in the "missing" time-steps.

- for a PriceDOMAIN Indicator, like a moving average, this can be a **`Close`** price of the first available bars, that gets replicated "period"-times back
- for multiplicative and exponentiating Indicator, that can be **`1`**
- for additive Indicator, that can be **`0`**

All the toys get aligned to fair values within the next "period" time-steps if the neutral values were algebraically correct, or in a little bit longer time, when substituted values were "just approximations". Both the former and the latter case, is typically well back in time to skew the future indicator values and to somehow bother the actual flow of current decisions, based on the recent indicator outputs.

Comment: Setting AD to be 0 for the first period worked. But I ran into an issue when calculating the money flow multiplier when ( high - low ) is equal to 0, because dividing by 0 is infinity. Do the same guidlines apply in that case? Or is the AD simply 0 for that period?

Comment: (a) MFM is not convoluted at all, so need not bother at all, (b) in case any ( high - low ) == 0, both the elements in the enumerator would get also zero, having zero difference, so one could set Money Flow inside such a crippled bar zero straigh. So, besides the protection from DIV!0, the sense is kept. And no money flow in a zero-sized candle seems also coherent with such market situation, doesn't it?

Comment: To add to this, there's a general "initialization" value for most indicators like this.  EMA uses SMA, ADX uses an average of `dx` values.  Here's a [code sample for ADX](https://github.com/DaveSkender/Stock.Indicators/blob/d434b7209391d7faef86178c70f630a5daeaf531/indicators/Adx/Adx.cs) (not same as AD above).